# Python Script Boot error in Raspberry pi terminal

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

[image]

I am trying to run a **python google speech recognition** script at the boot of the raspberry pi but gives the following error. I have used **.bashrc** and **rc.local** and **crontab -e** methods but all of them gives the same error. The script works super fine when I run it using python shell and even when I try to run the script by typing manually the command python3  in the terminal. But it gives errors only when I try to run at the boot. My raspberry pi is a **3B+ model** and the OS installed is **Raspberry pi OS(32bit)**.

In my `rc.local` I have:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e 
# 
# rc.local 
# 
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel. # Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other # value on error. 
# 
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution 
# bits. 
# 
# By default this script does nothing.  
# Print the IP address 
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true if [ "$_IP" ]; then   printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP" fi  
sudo python3 /home/pi/Desktop/files/greet.py  
exit 0
```

I get the error when I replace the line in rc.local with `sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/files/greet.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/files/greet.py", line 7, in <module>
    import speak
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/files/speak.py", line 13, in <module>
    from google.cloud import speech
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/speech/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.speech_v1 import SpeechClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .services.speech import SpeechClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/services/speech/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .client import SpeechClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/speech_v1/services/speech/client.py", line 25, in <module>
    from google.api_core import gapic_v1  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from google.api_core.gapic_v1 import config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/config.py", line 23, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from grpc import _compression
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/_compression.py", line 15, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc
ImportError: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)
```

Comment: *what* is in your rc.local? Incidentally, don't post screenshots: copy paste

Comment: My bad sudo nano /etc/rc.local rc.local suppose to be a file used for boot the script. Im sorry I could only get a screenshot. @2e0byo

Comment: sorry: I know what rc. local is, I want to know what's *in* it (i.e. what you're trying to run).  At any rate, you need to edit the post to put the line you actually added to startup files to run your script, and the line which works in a console. To copy-paste from lxterminal, select the text with the mouse and either go edit -> copy or Shift-Ctrl-c.  Incidentally, shot in the dark, but using the full path to python when you call the script at boot might get things going.

Comment: rc.local contains these lines (updated the question above) and I have properly mentioned the full path. @2e0byo

Comment: yeah, this belongs *in the question* (where I've added it).  You don't need sudo rc.local is run as root anyhow IIRC.  What happens if you replace `python3` with the full path to python3?  What happens if you run *exactly the same command*(the last line) in a terminal?

Comment: same error occurs when I give ```sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/files/greet.py``` @2e0byo

Comment: What do you mean?  Do you mean: the same error occurs when you run `sudo /usr/bin/python3 ..` *in a terminal*, or that if you use the whole path (without sudo) in rc.local you get this import error?  Regardless, could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70226038/edit) the question to specify.   There's a good q here, but it's currently rather hard to get at what's happening.

Comment: yay!  ... and what happens if you take sudo *out* of rc.local?  And what happens if you run that command as root in a terminal?

Comment: I tried that works fine but I need to boot the script when the raspberry pi boots itself @2e0byo

Comment: *what* did you try?  I asked *two* questions: 1. what happens without sudo, and 2. what happens if you run *exactly* the same line, as root, in a terminal.

Comment: 1. gives errors 2. runs perfectly fine @2e0byo

Comment: righty oh.  So some difference between the env in which your `rc.local` is running and the env in which you run in a terminal causes the problem.  Write a script to log the env---save the value of `$PATH` `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, maybe `$LD_PRELOAD`, etc, and find which makes the difference (you should be able to test which is causing it by temporarily modifying the var in question `PATH=... python3 script.py`.  When you have found the difference, you need either to `export`  the new var or do the same thing with prefixing in `rc.local`.  This is a *very weird* problem btw.

Comment: @2e0byo thankyou the without sudo thing worked. How ever I had to replace all the file paths in my script to /home/pi/<path to file> how ever it works now thank you very much for the help and for the advice